# Quick way to create skeleton .CPP files for each .H file

Tags: batch-file, automation

I have a header-only library with loads of .h files and I want to test each file works by having a .cpp file for each .h file with the same base file-name, which is empty except for `#include`-ing the relevant .h file.

e.g. I have a.h, b.h, c.h and want to create a.cpp: `include "a.h"` etc

Is there a neat way to do this, preferably in a Windows setting, automatically? A `FOR` command or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (*.h) DO IF NOT EXIST %%~ni.cpp >%%~ni.cpp ECHO #include "%%i"
```

should do that task. Needs small mods if you want non-pure-alphamer filenames.

Running from the prompt, use the FOR line only, reduce each `%%` to `%`

won't overwrite any existing .CPP files

Comment: Thanks to both - hard to chose my favourite but this one edges it for checking if the file exists already.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` to loop through all `*.h`, and for each one `echo` the `#include` to a `.cpp` with the same base name.

You can put this in a batch file and run it:

```
for %%h in (*.h) do (
    echo #include "%%h" > "%%~nh.cpp"
)
```

Or do it directly at the command line like this:

```
for %h in (*.h) do echo #include "%h" > "%~nh.cpp"
```